# ElasticSearch 'bucket_script' not executing when one of the bucket paths resolves to 'null'

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

Let's assume there's a (simplified) index:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "numeric_field_sometimes_empty": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "numeric_field_always_present": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with numeric fields that may or may not be present in some (potentially all filtered) docs:

```
POST test/_doc
{
  "numeric_field_always_present": 10  
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "numeric_field_always_present": 20  
}
```

I'm wanting to execute a `bucket_script` to calculate certain trends and since `bucket_script` needs to be a child of a multi-bucket agg, I simulate one using `filters`. After that nothing stands in the way of creating my numeric single-bucket sub-aggs like so:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "multibucket_simulator": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "all": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_empty": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "numeric_field_sometimes_empty"
          }
        },
        "avg_non_null": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "numeric_field_always_present"
          }
        },
        "diff": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "now": "avg_empty.value",
              "before": "avg_non_null.value"
            },
            "script": """
              return (params.now != null ? params.now : 0) 
                   - (params.before != null ? params.before : 0)
            """,
            "format": "###.##"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since I know that some of those sub-aggs' results may be `null` (a strict `null` type, not `0`), I check whether that was the case with the ternary operators and proceed to return the value difference. This yields:

```
{
  "aggregations":{
    "multibucket_simulator":{
      "buckets":{
        "all":{
          "doc_count":2,
          "avg_non_null":{
            "value":15.0
          },
          "avg_empty":{
            "value":null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with the `diff` bucket script sub-agg being fully left out. That's suboptimal...

I've tried removing `.value` from the paths so I can access and check `.value` directly in the script -- to no avail.

The question is then -- why are the `null` buckets being skipped and, also, is there an alternative besides `bucket_script` for this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs state that

> The specified metric must be numeric and the script must return a
> numeric value.

I suppose it's a matter of discussion whether `null` falls into that category.

---

**EDIT 1**

With that being said, setting a [`missing`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html#_missing_value) parameter on each `avg` agg solves this problem.

---

#### **EDIT 2 & Actual Anwer**

It was the [`gap_policy`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#gap-policy). It defaults to `skip` and needed to be set to `insert_zeros`. [Here's the reason](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/pipeline/BucketHelpers.java#L176).